# JS Canvas movement animation loop

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have an object rendered to a canvas. I'm trying to get the object to move along a set path on a loop. Here is what I have:

```js
// Canvas Element
var canvas = null;

// Canvas Draw
var ctx = null;

// Static Globals
var tileSize = 16,
    mapW = 10,
    mapH = 10;

// Instances of entities
var entities = [
  // A single entity that starts at tile 28, and uses the setPath() function
  {
    id: 0,
    tile: 28,
    xy: tileToCoords(28),
    width: 16,
    height: 24,
    speedX: 0,
    speedY: 0,
    logic: {
      func: 'setPath',
      // These are the parameters that go into the setPath() function
      data: [0, ['down', 'up', 'left', 'right'], tileToCoords(28), 0]
    },
    dir: {up:false, down:false, left:false, right:false}
  }
];

// Array for tile data
var map = [];

window.onload = function(){

  // Populate the map array with a blank map and 4 walls
  testMap();
  
  canvas = document.getElementById('save');
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // Add all the entities to the map array and start their behavior
  for(var i = 0; i < entities.length; ++i){

    map[entities[i].tile].render.object = entities[i].id;

    if(entities[i].logic){        
      window[entities[i].logic.func].apply(null, entities[i].logic.data);
    }
  }

  drawGame(map);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    mainLoop();
  });
};

function drawGame(map){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // We save all the entity data for later so the background colors don't get rendered on top
  var tileObjData = [];

  for(var y = 0; y < mapH; ++y){
    for(var x = 0; x < mapW; ++x){

      var currentPos = ((y*mapW)+x);

      ctx.fillStyle = map[currentPos].render.base;
      ctx.fillRect(x*tileSize, y*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);

      var thisObj = map[currentPos].render.object;

      if(thisObj !== false){

        thisObj = entities[thisObj];
        var originX = thisObj.xy.x;
        var originY = thisObj.xy.y;
        tileObjData.push(
          {
            id: thisObj.id,
            originX: originX, 
            originY: originY, 
            width: thisObj.width, 
            height: thisObj.height,
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Draw all the entities after the background tiles are drawn
  for(var i = 0; i < tileObjData.length; ++i){
    drawEntity(tileObjData[i].id, tileObjData[i].originX, tileObjData[i].originY, tileObjData[i].width, tileObjData[i].height);
  }
}

// Draws the entity data
function drawEntity(id, posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY){

  var offX = posX + entities[id].speedX;
  var offY = posY + entities[id].speedY;
  
  ctx.fillStyle = '#00F';
  ctx.fillRect(offX, offY + sizeX - sizeY, sizeX, sizeY);

  entities[id].xy.x = offX;
  entities[id].xy.y = offY;
}

// Redraws the canvas with the browser framerate
function mainLoop(){
  drawGame(map);

  for(var i = 0; i < entities.length; ++i){
    animateMove(i, entities[i].dir.up, entities[i].dir.down, entities[i].dir.left, entities[i].dir.right);
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    mainLoop();
  });
}

// Sets the speed, direction, and collision detection of an entity
function animateMove(id, up, down, left, right){

  var prevTile = entities[id].tile;

  if(up){

    var topLeft = {x: entities[id].xy.x, y: entities[id].xy.y};
    var topRight = {x: entities[id].xy.x + entities[id].width - 1, y: entities[id].xy.y};

    if(!map[coordsToTile(topLeft.x, topLeft.y - 1)].state.passable || !map[coordsToTile(topRight.x, topRight.y - 1)].state.passable){
      entities[id].speedY = 0;
    }
    else{
      entities[id].speedY = -1;
    }
  }
  else if(down){

    var bottomLeft = {x: entities[id].xy.x, y: entities[id].xy.y + entities[id].width - 1};
    var bottomRight = {x: entities[id].xy.x + entities[id].width - 1, y: entities[id].xy.y + entities[id].width - 1};

    if(!map[coordsToTile(bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y + 1)].state.passable || !map[coordsToTile(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y + 1)].state.passable){
      entities[id].speedY = 0;
    }
    else{
      entities[id].speedY = 1;
    }
  }
  else{
    entities[id].speedY = 0;
  }

  if(left){

    var bottomLeft = {x: entities[id].xy.x, y: entities[id].xy.y + entities[id].width - 1};
    var topLeft = {x: entities[id].xy.x, y: entities[id].xy.y};

    if(!map[coordsToTile(bottomLeft.x - 1, bottomLeft.y)].state.passable || !map[coordsToTile(topLeft.x - 1, topLeft.y)].state.passable){
      entities[id].speedX = 0;
    }
    else{
      entities[id].speedX = -1;
    }
  }
  else if(right){

    var bottomRight = {x: entities[id].xy.x + entities[id].width - 1, y: entities[id].xy.y + entities[id].width - 1};
    var topRight = {x: entities[id].xy.x + entities[id].width - 1, y: entities[id].xy.y};

    if(!map[coordsToTile(bottomRight.x + 1, bottomRight.y)].state.passable || !map[coordsToTile(topRight.x + 1, topRight.y)].state.passable){
      entities[id].speedX = 0;
    }
    else{
      entities[id].speedX = 1;
    }
  }
  else{
    entities[id].speedX = 0;
  }

  entities[id].tile = coordsToTile(entities[id].xy.x + (entities[id].width / 2), entities[id].xy.y + (tileSize / 2));
  map[entities[id].tile].render.object = id;

  if(prevTile !== entities[id].tile){
    map[prevTile].render.object = false;
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////
// THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE //
//////////////////////////////////////
// A function that can be used by an entity to move along a set path
// id = The id of the entity using this function
// path = An array of strings that determine the direction of movement for a single tile
// originPoint = Coordinates of the previous tile this entity was at. This variable seems to be where problems happen with this logic. It should get reset for every tile length moved, but it only gets reset once currently.
// step = The current index of the path array 
function setPath(id, path, originPoint, step){

  // Determine if the entity has travelled one tile from the origin
  var destX = Math.abs(entities[id].xy.x - originPoint.x);
  var destY = Math.abs(entities[id].xy.y - originPoint.y);

  if(destX >= tileSize || destY >= tileSize){
    // Go to the next step in the path array
    step = step + 1;
    if(step >= path.length){
      step = 0;
    }
    // Reset the origin to the current tile coordinates
    originPoint = entities[id].xy;
  }
  
  // Set the direction based on the current index of the path array
  switch(path[step]) {

    case 'up':
      entities[id].dir.up = true;
      entities[id].dir.down = false;
      entities[id].dir.left = false;
      entities[id].dir.right = false;
      break;

    case 'down':
      entities[id].dir.up = false;
      entities[id].dir.down = true;
      entities[id].dir.left = false;
      entities[id].dir.right = false;
      break;

    case 'left':
      entities[id].dir.up = false;
      entities[id].dir.down = false;
      entities[id].dir.left = true;
      entities[id].dir.right = false;
      break;

    case 'right':
      entities[id].dir.up = false;
      entities[id].dir.down = false;
      entities[id].dir.left = false;
      entities[id].dir.right = true;
      break;
  };

  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    setPath(id, path, originPoint, step);
  });
}

// Take a tile index and return x,y coordinates
function tileToCoords(tile){

  var yIndex = Math.floor(tile / mapW);
  var xIndex = tile - (yIndex * mapW);

  var y = yIndex * tileSize;
  var x = xIndex * tileSize;
  return {x:x, y:y};
}

// Take x,y coordinates and return a tile index
function coordsToTile(x, y){

  var tile = ((Math.floor(y / tileSize)) * mapW) + (Math.floor(x / tileSize));
  return tile;
}

// Generate a map array with a blank map and 4 walls
function testMap(){
  for(var i = 0; i < (mapH * mapW); ++i){

    // Edges

    if (
      // top
      i < mapW || 
      // left
      (i % mapW) == 0 || 
      // right
      ((i + 1) % mapW) == 0 || 
      // bottom
      i > ((mapW * mapH) - mapW)
    ) {

      map.push(
        {
          id: i,
          render: {
            base: '#D35',
            object: false,
            sprite: false
          },
          state: {
            passable: false
          }
        },
      );

    }
    else{

      // Grass

      map.push(
        {
          id: i,
          render: {
            base: '#0C3',
            object: false,
            sprite: false
          },
          state: {
            passable: true
          }
        },
      );

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <style>

    body{
      background-color: #000;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      color: #FFF;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    main{
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 10px auto;
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .game{
      width: 1000px;
      height: 1000px;
      position: relative;
    }

    canvas{
      image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
      image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;
      image-rendering: pixelated;
      image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    }

    .game canvas{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 800px;
      height: 800px;
    }

  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
  
  <main>
    <div class="game">
      <canvas id="save" width="200" height="200" style="z-index: 1;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </main>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem is with the `setPath()` function, and more specifically I think it's something with the `originPoint` variable. The idea is that `setPath()` moves the object one tile per `path` string, and `originPoint` should be the coordinates of the last tile visited (so it should only get updated once the object coordinates are one tile length away from the `originPoint`). Right now it only gets updated the first time and then stops. Hopefully someone can point out what I got wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition to change the path direction I change it to have conditions for each direction, something like:

```
if ((entities[id].dir.left  && entities[id].xy.x <= tileSize) ||    
  (entities[id].dir.right && entities[id].xy.x >= tileSize*8) || 
  (entities[id].dir.up    && entities[id].xy.y <= tileSize) ||
  (entities[id].dir.down  && entities[id].xy.y >= tileSize*8)) {
```

and the originPoint was just a reference you should do:

```
originPoint = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(entities[id].xy));
```

See the working code below

```js
// Canvas Element
var canvas = null;

// Canvas Draw
var ctx = null;

// Static Globals
var tileSize = 16,
    mapW = 10,
    mapH = 10;

// Instances of entities
var entities = [
  // A single entity that starts at tile 28, and uses the setPath() function
  {
    id: 0,
    tile: 28,
    xy: tileToCoords(28),
    width: 16,
    height: 24,
    speedX: 0,
    speedY: 0,
    logic: {
      func: 'setPath',
      // These are the parameters that go into the setPath() function
      data: [0, ['down', 'left', 'down', 'left', 'up', 'left', 'left', 'right', 'up', 'right', 'down','right', "up"], tileToCoords(28), 0]
    },
    dir: {up:false, down:false, left:false, right:false}
  }
];

// Array for tile data
var map = [];

window.onload = function(){

  // Populate the map array with a blank map and 4 walls
  testMap();
  
  canvas = document.getElementById('save');
  ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

  // Add all the entities to the map array and start their behavior
  for(var i = 0; i < entities.length; ++i){

    map[entities[i].tile].render.object = entities[i].id;

    if(entities[i].logic){        
      window[entities[i].logic.func].apply(null, entities[i].logic.data);
    }
  }

  drawGame(map);
  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    mainLoop();
  });
};

function drawGame(map){
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  // We save all the entity data for later so the background colors don't get rendered on top
  var tileObjData = [];

  for(var y = 0; y < mapH; ++y){
    for(var x = 0; x < mapW; ++x){

      var currentPos = ((y*mapW)+x);

      ctx.fillStyle = map[currentPos].render.base;
      ctx.fillRect(x*tileSize, y*tileSize, tileSize, tileSize);

      var thisObj = map[currentPos].render.object;

      if(thisObj !== false){

        thisObj = entities[thisObj];
        var originX = thisObj.xy.x;
        var originY = thisObj.xy.y;
        tileObjData.push(
          {
            id: thisObj.id,
            originX: originX, 
            originY: originY, 
            width: thisObj.width, 
            height: thisObj.height,
          }
        );
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Draw all the entities after the background tiles are drawn
  for(var i = 0; i < tileObjData.length; ++i){
    drawEntity(tileObjData[i].id, tileObjData[i].originX, tileObjData[i].originY, tileObjData[i].width, tileObjData[i].height);
  }
}

// Draws the entity data
function drawEntity(id, posX, posY, sizeX, sizeY){

  var offX = posX + entities[id].speedX;
  var offY = posY + entities[id].speedY;
  
  ctx.fillStyle = '#00F';
  ctx.fillRect(offX, offY + sizeX - sizeY, sizeX, sizeY);

  entities[id].xy.x = offX;
  entities[id].xy.y = offY;
}

// Redraws the canvas with the browser framerate
function mainLoop(){
  drawGame(map);

  for(var i = 0; i < entities.length; ++i){
    animateMove(i, entities[i].dir.up, entities[i].dir.down, entities[i].dir.left, entities[i].dir.right);
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    mainLoop();
  });
}

// Sets the speed, direction, and collision detection of an entity
function animateMove(id, up, down, left, right){

  var prevTile = entities[id].tile;

  if(up){

    var topLeft = {x: entities[id].xy.x, y: entities[id].xy.y};
    var topRight = {x: entities[id].xy.x + entities[id].width - 1, y: entities[id].xy.y};

    if(!map[coordsToTile(topLeft.x, topLeft.y - 1)].state.passable || !map[coordsToTile(topRight.x, topRight.y - 1)].state.passable){
      entities[id].speedY = 0;
    }
    else{
      entities[id].speedY = -1;
    }
  }
  else if(down){

    var bottomLeft = {x: entities[id].xy.x, y: entities[id].xy.y + entities[id].width - 1};
    var bottomRight = {x: entities[id].xy.x + entities[id].width - 1, y: entities[id].xy.y + entities[id].width - 1};

    if(!map[coordsToTile(bottomLeft.x, bottomLeft.y + 1)].state.passable || !map[coordsToTile(bottomRight.x, bottomRight.y + 1)].state.passable){
      entities[id].speedY = 0;
    }
    else{
      entities[id].speedY = 1;
    }
  }
  else{
    entities[id].speedY = 0;
  }

  if(left){

    var bottomLeft = {x: entities[id].xy.x, y: entities[id].xy.y + entities[id].width - 1};
    var topLeft = {x: entities[id].xy.x, y: entities[id].xy.y};

    if(!map[coordsToTile(bottomLeft.x - 1, bottomLeft.y)].state.passable || !map[coordsToTile(topLeft.x - 1, topLeft.y)].state.passable){
      entities[id].speedX = 0;
    }
    else{
      entities[id].speedX = -1;
    }
  }
  else if(right){

    var bottomRight = {x: entities[id].xy.x + entities[id].width - 1, y: entities[id].xy.y + entities[id].width - 1};
    var topRight = {x: entities[id].xy.x + entities[id].width - 1, y: entities[id].xy.y};

    if(!map[coordsToTile(bottomRight.x + 1, bottomRight.y)].state.passable || !map[coordsToTile(topRight.x + 1, topRight.y)].state.passable){
      entities[id].speedX = 0;
    }
    else{
      entities[id].speedX = 1;
    }
  }
  else{
    entities[id].speedX = 0;
  }

  entities[id].tile = coordsToTile(entities[id].xy.x + (entities[id].width / 2), entities[id].xy.y + (tileSize / 2));
  map[entities[id].tile].render.object = id;

  if(prevTile !== entities[id].tile){
    map[prevTile].render.object = false;
  }
}

//////////////////////////////////////
// THIS IS WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE //
//////////////////////////////////////
// A function that can be used by an entity to move along a set path
// id = The id of the entity using this function
// path = An array of strings that determine the direction of movement for a single tile
// originPoint = Coordinates of the previous tile this entity was at. This variable seems to be where problems happen with this logic. It should get reset for every tile length moved, but it only gets reset once currently.
// step = The current index of the path array 

function setPath(id, path, originPoint, step){
  if ((entities[id].dir.left  && entities[id].xy.x <= originPoint.x - tileSize) ||    
      (entities[id].dir.right && entities[id].xy.x >= originPoint.x + tileSize) || 
      (entities[id].dir.up    && entities[id].xy.y <= originPoint.y - tileSize) ||
      (entities[id].dir.down  && entities[id].xy.y >= originPoint.y + tileSize)) {
    // Go to the next step in the path array
    step = step + 1;
    if(step >= path.length){
      step = 0;
    }
    // Reset the origin to the current tile coordinates
    originPoint = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(entities[id].xy));
  }
  
  // Set the direction based on the current index of the path array
  switch(path[step]) {

    case 'up':
      entities[id].dir.up = true;
      entities[id].dir.down = false;
      entities[id].dir.left = false
      entities[id].dir.right = false;
      break;

    case 'down':
      entities[id].dir.up = false;
      entities[id].dir.down = true;
      entities[id].dir.left = false;
      entities[id].dir.right = false;
      break;

    case 'left':
      entities[id].dir.up = false;
      entities[id].dir.down = false;
      entities[id].dir.left = true;
      entities[id].dir.right = false;
      break;

    case 'right':
      entities[id].dir.up = false;
      entities[id].dir.down = false;
      entities[id].dir.left = false;
      entities[id].dir.right = true;
      break;
  };

  window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){
    setPath(id, path, originPoint, step);
  });
}

// Take a tile index and return x,y coordinates
function tileToCoords(tile){

  var yIndex = Math.floor(tile / mapW);
  var xIndex = tile - (yIndex * mapW);

  var y = yIndex * tileSize;
  var x = xIndex * tileSize;
  return {x:x, y:y};
}

// Take x,y coordinates and return a tile index
function coordsToTile(x, y){

  var tile = ((Math.floor(y / tileSize)) * mapW) + (Math.floor(x / tileSize));
  return tile;
}

// Generate a map array with a blank map and 4 walls
function testMap(){
  for(var i = 0; i < (mapH * mapW); ++i){

    // Edges

    if (
      // top
      i < mapW || 
      // left
      (i % mapW) == 0 || 
      // right
      ((i + 1) % mapW) == 0 || 
      // bottom
      i > ((mapW * mapH) - mapW)
    ) {

      map.push(
        {
          id: i,
          render: {
            base: '#D35',
            object: false,
            sprite: false
          },
          state: {
            passable: false
          }
        },
      );

    }
    else{

      // Grass

      map.push(
        {
          id: i,
          render: {
            base: '#0C3',
            object: false,
            sprite: false
          },
          state: {
            passable: true
          }
        },
      );

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <style>

    body{
      background-color: #000;
      display: flex;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      color: #FFF;
      font-size: 18px;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }

    main{
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 800px;
      margin: 10px auto;
      display: flex;
      align-items: flex-start;
      justify-content: center;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    .game{
      width: 1000px;
      height: 1000px;
      position: relative;
    }

    canvas{
      image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
      image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;
      image-rendering: pixelated;
      image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    }

    .game canvas{
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      width: 800px;
      height: 800px;
    }

  </style>
  
</head>
<body>
  
  <main>
    <div class="game">
      <canvas id="save" width="200" height="200" style="z-index: 1;"></canvas>
    </div>
  </main>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is maybe a bit closer than I got, but the behavior is different from what I intended. The object should only travel one tile length per string in the `path` array. So with `['down', 'up', 'left', 'right']`, it should move down _only_ 16px, up 16px, left 16px, and back right 16px.

Comment: No matter how much I move the logic still the same...  You need to have conditions for each direction.

Comment: You may ultimately be right about needing conditions for each directions, I'm not sure as I still haven't figured out the logic. This still doesn't solve for what I'm trying to do though. Your condition compares the object coordinates to specific coordinates on the map with `tilesize`. I want the destination map coordinates to be determined by the `path` array. I appreciate you taking the time to help though.

Comment: What do you think your `originPoint = entities[id].xy;` is doing?
 ...  I don't think that does what you are trying to do

Comment: My intent was for `originPoint` to store the coordinates of the previous tile the object visited. So when the object arrives at a new tile (has travelled one tile length of 16px), then `originPoint` gets updated to the new coordinates, and the next step of the `path` array happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198775/discussion-between-helder-sepulveda-and-jesse-dillman).

Answer (score 0):

As someone has already solved your bug...

This is more than a solution to your problem as the real problem you are facing is complexity, long complex if statements using data structures representing the same information in different ways making it difficult to see simple errors in logic.

On top of that you have some poor style habits that compound the problem.

A quick fix will just mean you will be facing the next problem sooner. You need to write in a ways that reduces the chances of logic errors due to increasing complexity

### Style

First style. Good style is very important

- Don't assign `null` to declared variables. JavaScript should not need to use `null`, the exception to the rule is that some C++ coders infected the DOM API with null returns because they did not understand JavaScipt (or was a cruel joke), and now we are stuck with null
- `window` is the default this (global this) and is seldom needed. Eg `window.requestAnimationFrame` is identical to just `requestAnimationFrame` and `window.onload` is identical to `onload`
- Don't pollute your code with inaccurate, redundant and/or obvious comments, use good naming to provide the needed information. eg:

  - `var map[];` has the comment `// array of tile data` Well really its an array that has data, who would have guessed, so the comment can be `// tiles` but then `map` is a rather ambiguous name. Remove the comment and give the variable a better name.
  - The comment `// Static Globals` above some vars. Javascript does not have static as a type so the comment is wrong and the "global's" part is "duh..."
- Use `const` to declare constants, move all the magic numbers to the top and define them as named `const`. A name has meaning, an number in some code has next to no meaning.
- Don't assign listener to the event name, it is unreliable and can be hijacked or overwritten. Always use `addEventListener` to assign an event listener
- Be very careful with your naming. eg the function named `coordsToTile` is confusing as it does not return a tile, it returns a tile index, either change the function name to match the functions behavior, or change the behavior to match the name.
- Don't use redundant intermediate functions, examples:

  - Your frame request   `requestAnimationFrame(function(){mainLoop()});` should skip the middle man and be  `requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);`
  - You use `Function.apply` to call the function `window[entities[i].logic.func].apply(null, entities[i].logic.data);`. `apply` is used to bind context `this` to the call, you don't use `this` in the function so you don't need use the apply. eg `window[entities[i].logic.func](...entities[i].logic.data);`

    BTW being forced to use bracket notation to access a global is a sign of poor data structure. You should never do that.
- JavaScript has an unofficial idiomatic styles, you should try to write JS in this style. Some examples from your code

  - `else` on the same line as closing `}`
  - Space after `if`, `else`, `for`, `function()` and befor `else`, opening block `{`
  - An id and an index are not the same, use `idx` or `index` for an index and `id` for an identifier

### Keep it simple

The more complex you make your data structures the harder it is for you to maintain them.

#### Structured

Define objects to encapsulate and organize your data.

- A global config object, that is transprotable ie can converted be to and from JSON. it contains all the magic numbers, defaults, type descriptions, and what not needed in the game.
- Create a set of global utilities that do common repeated tasks, ie create coordinates, list of directions.
- Define object that encapsulate the settings and behaviors specific only to that object.
- Use polymorphic object design, meaning that different objects use named common behaviors and properties. In the example all drawable object have a function called `draw` that takes an argument `ctx`, all objects that can be updated have a function called `update`

### Example

This example is a complete rewrite of your code and fixing your problem. It may be a little advanced, but it is only an example to look though an pick up some tips.

A quick description of the objects used.

Objects

- `config` is transportable config data
- `testMap` is an example map description
- `tileMap` does map related stuff
- `Path` Object encapsulating path logic
- `Entity` Object a single moving entity
- `Tile` Object representing a single tile
- `game` The game state manager

Games have states, eg loading, intro, inPlay, gameOver etc. If you do not plan ahead and create a robust state manager you will find it very difficult to move from one state to the next

I have included the core of a finite state manager. The state manager is responsible for updating and rendering. it is also responsible for all state changes.

```js
setTimeout(() => game.state = "setup", 0); // Will start the game
const canvas = document.getElementById('save');
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
const point = (x = 0, y = 0) => ({x,y});
const dirs = Object.assign(
    [point(0, -1), point(1), point(0,1), point(-1)], { // up, right, down, left
        "u": 0,  // defines index for direction string characters
        "r": 1,
        "d": 2,
        "l": 3,
        strToDirIdxs(str) { return str.toLowerCase().split("").map(char => dirs[char]) },
    }
);

const config = { 
    pathIdx: 28,
    pathTypes: {
        standard: "dulr",
        complex: "dulrldudlruldrdlrurdlurd",
    },
    tile: {size: 16},
    defaultTileName: "grass",
    entityTypes: {
        e: {
            speed: 1 / 32, // in fractions of a tile per frame
            color: "#00F",
            size: {x:16, y:24},
            pathName: "standard",
        },
        f: {
            speed: 1 / 16, // in fractions of a tile per frame
            color: "#08F",
            size: {x:18, y:18},
            pathName: "complex",
        },        
    },
    tileTypes: {
        grass: {
            style: {baseColor: "#0C3", object: false, sprite: false},
            state: {passable: true}
        },
        wall: {
            style: {baseColor: "#D35", object: false, sprite: false},
            state: {passable: false}
        },
    },
}
const testMap = {
    displayChars: {
        " " : "grass",  // what characters mean
        "#" : "wall", 
        "E" : "grass", // also entity spawn
        "F" : "grass", // also entity spawn
    },
    special: { // spawn enties and what not
        "E"(idx) { entities.push(new Entity(config.entityTypes.e, idx)) },
        "F"(idx) { entities.push(new Entity(config.entityTypes.f, idx)) }
    },
    map: // I double the width and ignor every second characters as text editors tend to make chars thinner than high
    //   0_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_ x coord
        "####################\n" +
        "##FF    ##        ##\n" +
        "##      ##        ##\n" +
        "##      ####      ##\n" +
        "##                ##\n" +
        "##  ####          ##\n" +
        "##                ##\n" +
        "##                ##\n" +
        "##              EE##\n" +
        "####################",
    //   0_1_2_3_4_5_6_7_8_9_ x coord
}
const entities = Object.assign([],{
    update() {
        for (const entity of entities) { entity.update() }
    },
    draw(ctx) {
        for (const entity of entities) { entity.draw(ctx) }
    },
});    
const tileMap = {
    map: [],
    mapToIndex(x, y) { return x + y  * tileMap.width },
    pxToIndex(x, y) { return x / config.tile.size | 0 + (y / config.tile.size | 0) * tileMap.width },
    tileByIdx(idx) { return tileMap.map[idx] },
    tileByIdxDir(idx, dir) { return tileMap.map[idx + dir.x + dir.y * tileMap.width] },
    idxByDir(dir) { return dir.x + dir.y * tileMap.width },
    create(mapConfig) {
        tileMap.length = 0;
        const rows = mapConfig.map.split("\n");
        tileMap.width = rows[0].length / 2 | 0;
        tileMap.height = rows.length;
        canvas.width = tileMap.width * config.tile.size;
        canvas.height = tileMap.height * config.tile.size;
        var x, y = 0;
        while (y < tileMap.height) {
            const row = rows[y];
            for (x = 0; x < tileMap.width; x += 1) {
                const char = row[x * 2];
                tileMap.map.push(new Tile(mapConfig.displayChars[char], x, y));
                if (mapConfig.special[char]) {
                    mapConfig.special[char](tileMap.mapToIndex(x, y));
                }
            }
            y++;
        }
    }, 
    update () {}, // stub
    draw(ctx) {
        for (const tile of tileMap.map) { tile.draw(ctx) }
    },
};
function Tile(typeName, x, y) {
    typeName = config.tileTypes[typeName] ? typeName : config.defaultTileName;
    const t = config.tileTypes[typeName];
    this.idx =  x + y * tileMap.width;
    this.coord = point(x * config.tile.size, y * config.tile.size);
    this.style =  {...t.style};
    this.state = {...t.state};    
}
Tile.prototype = {
    draw(ctx) {
        ctx.fillStyle = this.style.baseColor;
        ctx.fillRect(this.coord.x, this.coord.y, config.tile.size, config.tile.size);      
    }
};
function Path(pathName) {
    if (typeof config.pathTypes[pathName] === "string") { 
        config.pathTypes[pathName] = dirs.strToDirIdxs(config.pathTypes[pathName]);
    }
    this.indexes = config.pathTypes[pathName];
    this.current = -1;    
}
Path.prototype = {
    nextDir(tileIdx) {
        var len = this.indexes.length;
        while (len--) { // make sure we dont loop forever
            const dirIdx = this.indexes[this.current];
            if (dirIdx > - 1) {
                const canMove = tileMap.tileByIdxDir(tileIdx, dirs[dirIdx]).state.passable;
                if (canMove) { return dirs[dirIdx] }
            }
            this.current = (this.current + 1) % this.indexes.length;
        }
    }
};
function Entity(type, tileIdx) { 
    this.coord = point();
    this.move = point();
    this.color = type.color;
    this.speed = type.speed;
    this.size = {...type.size};
    this.path = new Path(type.pathName);
    this.pos = this.nextTileIdx = tileIdx;
    this.traveled = 1;  // unit dist between tiles 1 forces update to find next direction
}
Entity.prototype = {
    set dir(dir) {
        if (dir === undefined) { // dont move 
            this.move.y = this.move.x = 0;
            this.nextTileIdx = this.tileIdx;
        } else {
            this.move.x = dir.x * config.tile.size;
            this.move.y = dir.y * config.tile.size;
            this.nextTileIdx = this.tileIdx + tileMap.idxByDir(dir);
        }
    },
    set pos(tileIdx) {
        this.tileIdx = tileIdx;
        const tile = tileMap.map[tileIdx];
        this.coord.x = tile.coord.x + config.tile.size / 2;
        this.coord.y = tile.coord.y + config.tile.size / 2;
        this.traveled = 0;
    },
    draw(ctx) {
        const ox = this.move.x * this.traveled;
        const oy = this.move.y * this.traveled;
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;        
        ctx.fillRect(ox + this.coord.x -  this.size.x / 2, oy + this.coord.y  -  this.size.y / 2, this.size.x, this.size.y)
    },
    update(){
        this.traveled += this.speed;
        if (this.traveled >= 1) {
              this.pos = this.nextTileIdx;
              this.dir = this.path.nextDir(this.tileIdx);
        }
    }
};
const game = {
    currentStateName: undefined,
    currentState: undefined,
    set state(str) {
        if (game.states[str]) {
            if (game.currentState && game.currentState.end) { game.currentState.end() }
            game.currentStateName = str;
            game.currentState = game.states[str];
            if (game.currentState.start) { game.currentState.start() }
        }
    },
    states: {
        setup: {
            start() { 
                tileMap.create(testMap);
                game.state = "play"; 
            },
            end() {
                requestAnimationFrame(game.render); // start the render loop
                delete game.states.setup; // MAKE SURE THIS STATE never happens again
            },
        },
        play: {
            render(ctx) {    
                tileMap.update();
                entities.update();
                tileMap.draw(ctx);
                entities.draw(ctx);
            }
        }
    },
    renderTo: ctx,
    startTime: undefined,
    time: 0,
    render(time) {
        
        if (game.startTime === undefined) { game.startTime = time }
        game.time = time - game.startTime;
        if (game.currentState && game.currentState.render) { game.currentState.render(game.renderTo) }
        requestAnimationFrame(game.render);
    }
};
```

```css
body{
  background-color: #000;

}




canvas{
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="save" width="200" height="200" style="z-index: 1;"></canvas>
```

Please Note that there are some running states that have not been tested and as such may have a typo.

Also the tile map must be walled to contain entities or they will throw when they try to leave the playfield.

The code is designed to run in the snippet. To make it work in a standard page add above the very first line `setTimeout(() => game.state = "setup", 0);`  the line  `addEventListener(load", () = {` and after the very last line add the line `});`

Comment: Wow, thanks for taking the time and effort to make this! I had never seen `Object.assign` before, that will be massively helpful. The method you use to define the map is also much better than what I could have come up with.